# Why translation does not work for more than one line of text in my file?

Tags: python, html, translate, deepl

```py
import deepl
import pandas as pd

auth_key = "MY_API"  # Replace with your key
translator = deepl.Translator(auth_key)

input_file = "test.xlsx"
output_file = "output.xlsx"

# Read the entire Excel file without headers
df = pd.read_excel(input_file, header=None)

# Translate each cell in the DataFrame
translated_data = df.applymap(lambda text: translator.translate_text(str(text), target_lang="DE"))

# Save the translated data back to an Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    translated_data.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False)

print("Translation completed and saved to output.xlsx")
```

I tried to translate some text in `xlsx` file and when i add more data to my input file then program could not handle it.

I got `copywriting` in html format saved in `xlsx` file and i would like to translate it and save it as new still with html sings in it.

Maybe there is another, better way to achieve it then `Deepl` API.

input file: go.wetransfer.com/t-NzftoJCfYx

Comment: What do you mean by "program could not handle it"? Did you get an error message? If yes, please add the error to your question.

Comment: Could you post an example `test.xlsx` file here where translation fails?
It might be easier to add some intermediary checks (extract the strings from the excel file, print those, chuck them in the translator, print the translations) rather than doing all steps at once and wondering what fails.
Additionally, for translation with HTML tags you need to enable the proper tag handling, see here: https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python#text-translation-options

Comment: @Ada I mean my output file does not contains any data, only headers and it is empty, but when i have only one line of text it provides me with proper, translated output

Comment: @Gaze Here is my input file https://go.wetransfer.com/t-NzftoJCfYx

Comment: Please edit the question to include the file itself, as per the SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There seem to be three explanations: 1) `read_excel` didn't read any rows. Can  you add a `print` statement to count how many rows were loaded? 2) 'applymap` didn't create any rows. You seem to think that Deepl might be the problem. 3) `to_excel` didn't write out of all of the rows. If it did, the `ExcelWriter` hadn't closed the file properly.  
Can you isolate which explanation is most likely to be correct?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me using (`excel_example.xlsx` is a sample table I made in numbers and exported to excel, with A1="This is an example sentence", A2="This is another example sentence".):

1. `python` 3.10
2. `deepl` v1.15.0
3. `pandas` v2.1.2

```
import pandas as pd
import deepl

input_file = 'excel_example.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(input_file, header=None)
df.applymap(lambda text: print(text))
# prints the following:
# <stdin>:1: FutureWarning: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.
# Table 1
# This is an example sentence.
# This is another example sentence.
#      0
# 0  None
# 1  None
# 2  None
t = deepl.Translator('MY_API_KEY')
res = df.applymap(lambda text: t.translate_text(str(text), target_lang="DE"))
print(res)
# prints the following
#                                      0
# 0                            Tabelle 1
# 1           Dies ist ein Beispielsatz.
# 2  Dies ist ein weiterer Beispielsatz.
```

If your excel file has HTML tags in the text, you would need to enable HTML tag handling like so:

`res = df.applymap(lambda text: t.translate_text(str(text), target_lang="DE", tag_handling='html'))`

For any more concrete help (eg if writing back to the excel file doesn't work) we would need a specific error message.